# How to better handle Partial<T> interfaces

Tags: typescript

In the scenario below, I don't want to trust the untrusted object and want to check that each field is truthy before acting upon it. However, using the Partial generic, it does not infer that the field is not undefined when attempting to pass it to the function. Is there a better way to handle this?

```
export interface IFoo {
  id: number;
  value: string;
}

export function DoBar(obj: IFoo) {
  // do stuff
  return;
}

const untrustedObj: Partial<IFoo> = { id: 1, value: 'test' };

if (untrustedObj.id && untrustedObj.value) {
  DoBar(untrustedObj); // Error
}
```

error:

```
Argument of type 'Partial<IFoo>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'IFoo'.
  Types of property 'id' are incompatible.
    Type 'number | undefined' is not assignable to type 'number'.
      Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'number'.ts(2345)
```

Comment: See [microsoft/TypeScript#28882](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28882).  You'll either need a user defined type guard or some other [refactoring](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play//#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgSQDEII4BvAWACg5bEATALjiQFcBbAIzQG5q64AN0wAbVsGYBnGFGQBzPlQC+1UJFhx0rJNhgIISOABEIAIUxQAFBE4ArZkRIBKcnCjAYrKEh5wVVamwDaThtGVZpYHoAeTtmAAULPVEAHkcIAD44AF5XBCY4AEYAGiFRcWYAclRpSr9FIKQQ1nx6HNCUKAjUGLsAOnyG4PhWADVyvFywrsje2z7hMWBFBHQ4SxgATzBgCDWWtoBCbNyAIm16YHRkKNO4ADJ7uC2dvdDxpbhjs4urm-pTi5KDQ6CZzFYyAxmAdSosKu8Jn4nIp-NQgA) to make this work.

Answer (score 4):

You can write a [type guard function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards) using `is` to narrow the object's type:

```js
function hasKey<T, K extends keyof T>(obj: Partial<T>, key: K):
    obj is Partial<T> & { [k in K]: T[k] }
{
    return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, key);
}
```

Usage:

```js
if(hasKey(untrustedObj, 'id') && hasKey(untrustedObj, 'value')) {
  doBar(untrustedObj); // no type error
}
```

I've used `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty` as a more general solution to testing this, since you might want to check if a boolean property exists (rather than also checking if it's true).

[Playground Link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIDED2nkG8BQyywAJgFzIgCuAtgEbQDchyAbnADZUQUDOYUUAHNmAX3z4YVEAjDBMIZCUwAhOFAAUmOgCsKGbAEo84ydNnzFACzi8A0hACeAHgAqAGmR3kEAB6QQEl5kAGsnTBhkVwA+LV0KAAV1OU43aM8wxwo7QzIWIm0dYmCkqBSONOQAMjxkAG0Q4kU7AF0KVwaW5HECIiIoCDAqKEUAeV0IWQA6AAcoTDAFxxmIKZteUYB3EAT5lbLHKYRODjidDKdDMQkEBX5kaQEqfggScb1kUvLnA0xo5AAvLVSBQAIyedhcHjIADkkH4MO6zHwwEiGnWDkcGkeUGekDeuk8MNIMOMVRqGKc2PAuJeBPOsMh3FJxl6SlU6mpTzp7yu+HEQA)

Comment: Why not just [`return key in obj;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in)?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts The difference is that `key in obj` will be true also when `obj` inherits the `key` property from its prototype; for most use cases, you would want the object to have its own property, and if it didn't but its prototype did then that would probably indicate a bug. If you do want to explicitly use prototypal inheritance to share properties, then `key in obj` is correct. For normal class-based inheritance, properties defined by superclasses will still belong to the object itself.

Comment: I'm less worried about inheritance than about explicit `undefined` props like `{id: void 0, value: ""}`. I'd do [this](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play//#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgSQDEII4BvAWACg5bEATALjiQFcBbAIzQG5q64AN0wAbVsGYBnGFGQBzPlQC+1UJFhx0rJNhgIISOABEIAIUxQAFBE4ArZkRIBKcnCjAYrKEh5wVVbANpOG0ZVmlgJjgABQs9UQAeRwgAPjgAXlcEKIBGABohUXFmAHJUaRK-RS0dPQM4emB0aKgIMASAFQKAaThQVCR6STgAa2AATwh0OA6Uy346G3sZgoA6dbBWsElmboBtAF1qJ2YlxGGOuAAyOAAlYABHVgR3egTohGwRzp6UtMoaHR3J5vHBNm1JKtgII0ONLCMMmkYOMwMApnAlnsRgc4ABCdKZABE2ka6GQkUJTkU-gQ00spJabUsoSg4VQ9AKhOyhM5wjEwEpLgBAhM5isLLZkSp1H8QA) instead.

Comment: @jcalz You should post this as an actual potential answer. It's a better solution to the problem IMO

Comment: @JesseCarter fair enough, will do

Answer (score 3):

See [microsoft/TypeScript#28882](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28882) for why this doesn't work.  If an object is not of a discriminated union type, checking its properties will not narrow the type of the object itself.  You'll either need a [user defined type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards) or some other refactoring to make this work.

One such refactoring is to save the properties to their own variables, since TypeScript's compiler will narrow the type of variables if you check them:

```
const uId = untrustedObj.id;
const uValue = untrustedObj.value;
if (typeof uId !== "undefined" && typeof uValue !== "undefined") {
    DoBar({ id: uId, value: uValue }); // okay
}
```

My suggestion for a type guard function would look like this:

```
function definedProp<T, K extends keyof T>(
    obj: T, ...props: K[]
): obj is T & Required<Pick<T, K>> {
    return props.every(k => typeof obj[k] !== "undefined");
}
```

This will check to see that `obj` has a defined value for each key in the `props` array, and if so, it will narrow the passed-in `obj`.  Then you use it like this:

```
if (definedProp(untrustedObj, "id", "value")) {
    DoBar(untrustedObj); // okay
}
```

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play//#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgSQDEII4BvAWACg5bEATALjiQFcBbAIzQG5q64AN0wAbVsGYBnGFGQBzPlQC+1UJFhx0rJNhgIISOABEIAIUxQAFBE4ArZkRIBKcnCjAYrKEh5wVVbANpOG0ZVmlgegB5O2YABQs9UQAeRwgAPjgAXlcEJjgARgAaIVFxZgByVGkKv0V+akCkYNZ8emyQlChw1Gi7ADo8xSaWgDUyvBzQ7oi+237hMWBFBHQ4SxgATzBgCDXW9oBCLJyAIm16YHRkSNO4ADJ7uC2dvZDxpbhjs4urm-pTi5KDQ6CZzFYyAxmAcSotyu8Jn4nIp-NQ0VQtDo9AY4JdrkhInEoBAwMkAColADScFAqCQ9EkcAA1sBNm8yelLPw6DZ7HAKXB+kKwMSwJJmJSANoAXWoTmYvMQjLJDzgACVgABHVgIdz0ZJxBDYJnkqnpTLAgTuTzeOAikmSfrAQRoTaWJnZTIvXZrXmSpnSr4nODnel-AkA5HUfyrdZ4-5EkmWaY9SIxWwlU55U6ZuHAQFA7m0MEWZNdVNzKPKahAA)